# Acessar var global

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho o seguinte código

```
var myGlobal : String
func nomeDaFuncao () {
    // Preciso acessar a global
    myGlobal = "fff"
}
```

Como posso acessar a global dentro de uma função ou uma action ?
Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `self` caso for usar o atributo na mesma classe

```
self.myGlobal = "VALOR"
```

**Exemplo:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myGlobal : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myGlobal = "Teste"
    }
}
```

Lembre se usar `?` para atributos não obrigatórios e `!` para tributos obrigatórios